# Newline character in ui.xml file that makes it to the HTML

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I've got a ui.xml file with the following in it:

```
<g:TextArea>
    1. Line one

    2. Line two 
</g:TextArea>
```

Of course, in the final HTML, this is coming out as `1. Line one 2. Line two`, on a single line.

How can I cause the final HTML to include the desired newline characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of embedding the text in the tag, you could put it in the "text" attribute of the tag:

```
<g:TextArea text="Line 1&#10;Line 2"/>
```

The `&#10;` is a '\r'. This did the trick for me, but obviously it's not as elegant as enclosing the text within the tag itself.